# Powershell: Display a System.Object in Query Results

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-active-directory

having trouble including certain results in a query for AzureADSignInLogs.

I have the following statement, but would like to include more results that are `System.Objects`.

```
Get-AzureADAuditSignInLogs |
    Where-Object{$_.ClientAppUsed -like 'Exchange ActiveSync'} |
    Format-Table CreatedDateTime, UserPrincipalName, AppDisplayName, ClientAppUsed
```

On the end, i'd like to include an ErrorCode which falls under the Status parent:

[SCREENSHOT: Powershell Results of Get-AzureADSignInLogs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YfiHy.png)

But I'm not sure how to drill down to fetch the information then display it.
Is it possible in a `Format-Table`? Or does there have to be some other way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would handle the data before using Format-Table as this changes the structure of the data from an object perspective.

Please see the below where I have used a calculated property on a select-object statement.

```
Get-AzureADAuditSignInLogs |
    Where-Object{$_.ClientAppUsed -like 'Exchange ActiveSync'} |
    Select-Object CreatedDateTime, UserPrincipalName, AppDisplayName, ClientAppUsed, @{Name = "ErrorCode"; Expression = {$_.Status.ErrorCode}} |
    Format-Table
```

As I do not have a premium license I am unable to test the above in Azure.

Comment: Awesome!! Thanks so much that worked a treat!

Comment: You are welcome, please feel free to also up vote the answer (every point helps :) ).

Comment: I will as soon as I get more reputations.. still not enough :( Will come back to upvote!